# Social engine database conventions for mod creation

Tags: socialengine

I m new to **social engine module development**.I wud like to know some basic social engine convention.

- How do I get the default **social engine adapter** (the one I m already
  logged with & the one users r NOT)so that  I can use it to CRUD my database table.
- Are there two types of adapter needed for registered and
  guest(unregistered) users
- What are the other **social engine** database conventions.

PLS HELP ME, I M NOVICE.
THNX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this excellent tutorial from Marco Enrico: [The Complete Guide to Social Engine 4 Module Development](http://social-engine-tutorials.blogspot.ru/2012/07/complete-guide-to-social-engine-4.html)

Comment: I already found that and trying but he also avoided some necessary aspects. BTW can u tell me the difference between socialengine item owner and parent, or more specifically what getParent() and getOwner will return ? I wud be grateful, thnx

Comment: I answered about getParent() in your other question, check it :) As for getOwner(), it is row's owner (registered site user) and returns User_Model_User Object (application/modules/User/Model/User.php)

Comment: Yes I know that by default owner type is user but u can change it to whatever item u want,if so, what do u mean by row's owner (registered site user).What's then difference between row's parent and owner.Technically,I found dat both getOwner() n getParent() make a join on tables as per the matching id.
Thank u very much bro for the help.

Comment: Well, both methods are similar, but owner is user-related, for example for Forum_Model_Post:
protected $_parent_type = 'forum_topic';
protected $_owner_type = 'user';
Forum topic is parent for post, user is owner.

Comment: Yes, I got it now, Thank u very much.I just wondered what if owner is not a user...